# Wait for a specified amount of objects?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, wait

- Using [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025(VS.85).aspx):

  - Makes it possible, to wait for **one** or **all** of **specified objects** to change to a **singled** state

**Question:**

- How can one wait for a **specified** amount - such as `5`, for example

**Usage**

```
dwEvent = WaitForMultipleObjects(
                maxExpectedConnections,
                ghEventsA,
                TRUE,//but wait for a specified number instead
                INFINITE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the waitall flag to indicate that you want the wait to return when any object is signalled. When wait returns, remove the signalled object from the array of objects and wait again until you have N (e.g. 5 in your case) signalled objects.

Comment: Hi Neil, "waitall" flag - is this a predefined directive?

Comment: I meant pass FALSE in the bWaitAll parameter

Answer (score 0):

You could just wait several times for a single object each, until you have collected as many "ready" objects as you want.

Comment: But waiting on one object blocks the thred. How will you detect if another object becomes signalled?

Comment: I meant to still wait on all, but just until one becomes signaled with WaitForMultipleObjects(..., ..., FALSE, ...). Then wait on the remaining objects until the next becomes signaled and so on.

Comment: Pretty much the same thing you suggested, in fact.